# GStreamer streaming stopped, reason error (-5)

Tags: encoding, gstreamer, decoding, gstreamer-1.0

Every time I run my pipeline, it goes for a while, and then eventually crashes with, "streaming stopped, reason error (-5). I tried to debug the error, but actually got nothing specific that might be helpful.
My Gstramer pipeline:

```
'gst-launch-1.0',
'--gst-debug=*src*:5',
'-vvv',
'rtpbin', 'name=rtpbin', 'rtp-profile=avpf',
'fdsrc', 'timeout=1000000',
'!', 'queue',
'!', 'image/x-portable-pixmap,width=1280,height=720,framerate=30/1',
'!', 'pnmdec',
'!', 'videoconvert',
'!', 'x264enc', 'tune=zerolatency', 'speed-preset=1', 'dct8x8=true', 'quantizer=23', 'pass=qual',
'!', 'video/x-h264, profile=baseline',
'!', 'rtph264pay', 'ssrc=111110', 'pt=96',
'!', 'rtprtxqueue', 'max-size-time=2000', 'max-size-packets=0',
'!', 'rtpbin.send_rtp_sink_0',
'rtpbin.send_rtp_src_0',
'!', 'udpsink', 'bind-address=127.0.0.1', 'host=127.0.0.1', 'bind-port=5004', `port=${videoRtpPort}`,
'rtpbin.send_rtcp_src_0',
'!', 'udpsink', 'bind-address=127.0.0.1', 'host=127.0.0.1', `port=${videoRtcpPort}`, 'sync=false', 'async=false', 'udpsrc', 'port=5005',
'!', 'rtpbin.recv_rtcp_sink_0',
```

**The error:**

```
0:00:00.383847433  8025 0x55cb237fe940 DEBUG                basesrc gstbasesrc.c:2460:gst_base_src_get_range:<fdsrc0> calling create offset 5821984 length 4096, time 0
0:00:00.401808796  8025 0x55cb237fe940 DEBUG                basesrc gstbasesrc.c:2315:gst_base_src_do_sync:<fdsrc0> no sync needed
0:00:00.401819755  8025 0x55cb237fe940 DEBUG                basesrc gstbasesrc.c:2524:gst_base_src_get_range:<fdsrc0> buffer ok
0:00:00.401824818  8025 0x55cb237fe940 INFO                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:2860:gst_base_src_loop:<fdsrc0> pausing after gst_pad_push() = error
0:00:00.401828989  8025 0x55cb237fe940 DEBUG                basesrc gstbasesrc.c:2903:gst_base_src_loop:<fdsrc0> pausing task, reason error
0:00:00.401834372  8025 0x55cb237fe940 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:2950:gst_base_src_loop:<fdsrc0> error: Internal data stream error.
0:00:00.401837214  8025 0x55cb237fe940 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:2950:gst_base_src_loop:<fdsrc0> error: streaming stopped, reason error (-5)
```

**Interesting fact:**
If I enable debug mode, it stops working right away and crashes with the error;

### Update

Set debug for Queue element, and got the following:

```
0:00:00.947557704  4268 0x5607b98d5230 DEBUG         queue_dataflow gstqueue.c:1219:gst_queue_chain_buffer_or_list:<queue0> queue is full, waiting for free space
0:00:00.967780458  4268 0x5607b98d5230 WARN                   queue gstqueue.c:989:gst_queue_handle_sink_event:<queue0> error: Internal data stream error.
0:00:00.967813978  4268 0x5607b98d5230 WARN                   queue gstqueue.c:989:gst_queue_handle_sink_event:<queue0> error: streaming stopped, reason error (-5)
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFdSrc:fdsrc0: Internal data stream error.
Additional debug info:
gstbasesrc.c(2950): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFdSrc:fdsrc0:
streaming stopped, reason error (-5)
```

Seems like the queue is full, so how to solve the issue?

### Update 2

Seems that the problem is caused by pnmdec plugin. The following pipeline throws the same error:

```
'gst-launch-1.0',
'fdsrc', 'fd=0',
'!', 'queue',
'!', 'image/x-portable-pixmap,width=1280,height=720,framerate=20/1',
'!', 'pnmdec',
'!', 'fakesink', 'dump=true',
```

But the pipeline without pnmdec works fine. Any thoughts about the issue?

**One more interesting thing:**
I've noticed that the pipeline crashes after the following event:

```
GST_SCHEDULING gstpad.c:4329:gst_pad_chain_data_unchecked:<pnmdec0:sink>[00m called chainfunction &gst_video_decoder_chain with buffer 0x7f97c8310d80, returned error
```

I tried to google it but found nothing.

Comment: One possibility is that your `x264enc` (which uses software encoding) can't keep up after a while and starts running behind.

Comment: Try to rebuild your pipeline from scratch: add a new element only after the previous configuration has been tested properly and shows no problems. You will find out exactly which element is causing the problem and then we will be able to help you. The pipeline is just too complex to debug as is.

Comment: @karlphillip I've edited my question and added a new simple pipeline. You were right, the best way to debug is to simplify the pipeline. So any thoughts about pnmdec issue?

Comment: Could it be the properties that are being configured before `pnmdec`? I mean, does something simple like this even work on your system? `gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=test.pnm ! pnmdec ! videoconvert ! autovideosink` If it works, add the properties to this pipeline and see if it breaks.

Comment: @karlphillip well, It works fine with and without properties. It seems like there is a kind of buffer inside of pnmdec and it doesn't have time to process a big chunk of stream, idk. That means the pipeline crashes when pnmdec decodes a stream from fdsrc. I thought that queue should help, but seems like it didn't